# Creating points with co-ordinates in QGIS to upload to GPS

Tags: qgis, point, gps

I have generated a random point within a set area. I have done this using the Google Maps plugin layer. The CRS is set to WGS 84.

I want to get the co-ordinates for this point so I went into the attribute table and used the $X and $Y functions which gave me some numbers. I read these were in UTM so used an online converter to put them into lat long but they always end up being in the ocean somewhere.

All I want to do is to create a random point in QGIS, get the co-ordinates, save it as a GPX file which I have tried to do also, and then upload it into my Garmin GPS using the GPS Toolbox. When I save it as a GPX file it still never comes up in the upload to GPS dropdown box but I am not sure this would even matter as the co-ordinates never seem to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Maps with the Openlayers plugin, the project CRS should be `EPSG:3857`, not UTM.

Anyway, if you create a new point layer, you can choose that it should be in `EPSG:4326 WGS84 lat/lon`.

With this setting,you can use `Rightclick -> Save As ...` to choose GPX as output format with no further transformation.

Using the GPS Toolbox should also be no problem with data in EPSG:4326.

You can check the layers extent in the Properties,metadata section. It should be within +/-180/90.